# steamcmd to launch game automatically

Tags: steam

Wondering if it is possible to launch steam game through steamcmd.

to download the game, I used a powershell command

```
.\steamcmd.exe +login <username> <password> +app_update <game_id> validate +quit
```

the game will then appear to be at steamapps folder in the same directory. However, when I click the game.exe it gives me an error saying that some of the dlls is missing or unable to initialize steam API
The games that I downloaded are metro last light redux and tomb raider.

Is there a way to launch a steam game from steamcmd without relying on the steam ui?

Any input helps. 
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Searching for the same since quite a while to have a somewhat portable Steam....
Only option in steamcmd i found is:
app_run :  [LaunchOptionIndex] [Arguments]

Which actually tries to launch the game, but you still end with the same steam.dll missing error - so this only works with complete DRM free steam games, which are mostly only the dedicated servers > SteamCMD seems not to include Steam DRM so this is no option :(